# Create database trigger in Spring

Tags: spring, database, triggers

I have a .sql file under resources where I want to set up a trigger.
The problem I'm facing is due to the syntax: apparently it doesn't accept neither "delimiter" nor "begin...end". This is my code so far:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS myTrigger;
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
       AFTER UPDATE
       ON table_name
       FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        select avg(table.param)
        into @myParam
        from table
        WHERE table.id = NEW.id;
        UPDATE table2
        -- Do some stuff;
    end//
Delimiter ;
```

It gives me errors like:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'DELIMITER // DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS adaptGradesToAverage' at
> line 1

I tried to remove the delimiter and only have one action in the begin-end, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
           AFTER UPDATE
           ON table_name
           FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE table2
            -- Do some stuff;
        end;
```

but then it gives me this kind of errors:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 1